# Removing rows in list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove a list of accounts from a CSV and delete/exclude whatever row they were in. The accounts are in two separate columns.

I've tried using isin to exclude them, but it just removes the strings and not the whole row.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['samaccountname', 'employeeid', 'manager', 'title']
df = pd.read_csv('accounts.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,4], header=0, names=cols)
acs = ['josmith', 'jesmith']

samaccountname employeeid manager title
josmith        12345      adsmith president
jpsmith        67890      jesmith advisor
jadoe          10000      jpsmith supervisor
```

Output should look like this.

```
samaccountname employeeid manager title
jadoe          10000      jpsmith supervisor
```

Comment: is acs the list of accounts you want to remove?

Comment: ```cols = ['samaccountname', 'employeeid', 'manager', 'title']
df = pd.DataFrame([["josmith", 12345, "adsmith", "president"], ["jpsmith", 67890, "jesmith", "advisor"],
      ["jadoe", 10000, "jpsmith", "supervisor"]])
df.columns = cols
acs = ['josmith', 'jesmith']
df = df[~df.samaccountname.isin(acs)]
df = df[~df.manager.isin(acs)]
print(df)```

Comment: acs is the list of accounts to remove yes.

Comment: @KonstantinGrigorov That was what I was looking for, thanks very much.

Comment: No worries, here to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have not tested

```
 print (df.tail(1))
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is after

Comment: This would print the last row from the dataframe